# Query Mapbox dataset - retrieve nearest 10 stores

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to query a MapBox dataset, which contains dozens of locations of, let's say, stores, and retrieve the nearest 10 to a given user location. Distances should be calculated by driving and not as the crow flies. We'd be using the JS web API.

We've searched the webs and MapBox API but couldn't find anything relevant to our use case.

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox has several tools for batch-calculating driving *times*, but not yet for driving *distances*. The [Directions API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=JavaScript#directions) is the only thing that returns the latter, but only one origin-destination pair at a time.

By "nearest", most logistics/optimization problems are really looking at travel time. Mapbox's [Matrix API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=JavaScript#directions-matrix) solves this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use the mapzen isochrone API which returns GeoJSON polygon(s), then use turf.within on the polygon to find the nearest locations.